# GridSearch / make_scorer strange results with xgboost model

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I am tryting to use sklearn's gridsearch with a model created by xgboost. To do this, I am creating a custom scorer based on ndcg evaluation. I am successfully able to use Snippet 1 but it is too messy / hacky, I would prefer to use good old sklearn to simplify the code. I tried to implement GridSearch and the results is completely off: for the same X and y sets I get NDCG@k = 0.8 with Snippet 1 versus 0.5 with Snippet 2. Obviously there something I am not doing right here ...

The following pieces of code return very different results:

Snippet1:

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

max_depth = [6]
learning_rate = [0.22]
n_estimators = [43]
reg_alpha = [0.1]
reg_lambda = [10]
for md in max_depth:
    for lr in learning_rate:
        for ne in n_estimators:
            for ra in reg_alpha:
                for rl in reg_lambda:

                    xgb = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob', 
                                        max_depth=md, 
                                        learning_rate=lr, 
                                        n_estimators=ne,
                                        reg_alpha=ra, 
                                        reg_lambda=rl,
                                        subsample=0.6, colsample_bytree=0.6, seed=0)
                    print([md, lr, ne])

                    score = []
                    for train_index, test_index in kf:
                        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
                        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

                        xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
                        y_pred = xgb.predict_proba(X_test)

                        score.append(ndcg_scorer(y_test, y_pred))

                    print('all scores: %s' % score)
                    print('average score: %s' % np.mean(score))
```

Snippet2:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

params = {
    'max_depth':[6], 
    'learning_rate':[0.22], 
    'n_estimators':[43],
    'reg_alpha':[0.1], 
    'reg_lambda':[10],
    'subsample':[0.6], 
    'colsample_bytree':[0.6]
}
xgb = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob',seed=0)
scorer = make_scorer(ndcg_scorer, needs_proba=True)    
gs = GridSearchCV(xgb, params, cv=5, scoring=scorer, verbose=10, refit=False)
gs.fit(X,y)
gs.best_score_
```

While snippet1 gives me the result as expected, the score returned by Snippet2 is not consistent with the ndcg_scorer.

Comment: First inconsistence which i see - you are using KFold with n_folds=2 implicitly in second snippet, instead of StratifiedKFold with n_folds=5 like in first. Create same StratifiedKFold second time and pass it into GridSearchCV as cv parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with cv in`GridSearchCV(xgb, params, cv=5, scoring=scorer, verbose=10, refit=False)`. It can recieve a KFold / StratifiedKFold instead of an int. Unlike what is says in the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) it seems that by default an agrument of type 'int' is not calling StratifiedKFold another function maybe KFold.